# Utilizando funções

Tags: c

Boa tarde! Estou implementando um jogo de pedra, papel e tesoura, onde ocorre a aplicação de funções, com e sem argumento e retorno. Fiquei em dúvida, após o programa identificar as opções do usuário e do computador, pois não consegui acertar o resultado final Ex: "Pedra amassa tesoura" mas a casos onde não escolhi tesoura e nem pedra.

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < time.h >

    int ler_jogada() {
        int jog_usuario;

        printf("Digite (1) para pedra, (2) para papel, (3) para tesoura: ");
        scanf("%d", & jog_usuario);
        return jog_usuario;
        while (jog_usuario < 1 || jog_usuario > 3) {
            printf("Valor invalido, informe outro!");
            scanf("%d", & jog_usuario);
            fflush(stdin);
        }
        return jog_usuario;
    }

int ler_comp() {
    int jogada_comp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    jogada_comp = 1 + rand() % 4;

    return jogada_comp;
}
void imprime_jog(int jog_usuario, int jogada_comp) {
    switch (jog_usuario) {
        case 1:
            printf("\nVoce escoheu pedra!");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nVoce escolheu papel!");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nVoce escolheu tesoura!");
            break;
    }
    switch (jogada_comp) {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEscolhi pedra!");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\nEscolhi papel!");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nEscolhi tesoura!");
            break;
    }
}
int calc_resultado(int jog_usuario, int jogada_comp) {
    if (jog_usuario == 1 && jogada_comp == 2) {
        printf("\nPapel cobre pedra!");
        return 1;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == 1 && jogada_comp == 3) {
        printf("\nPedra amassa tesoura!");
        return 2;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == 2 && jogada_comp == 1) {
        printf("\nPapel cobre pedra!");
        return 2;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == 2 && jogada_comp == 3) {
        printf("\nTesoura corta papel!");
        return 1;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == 3 && jogada_comp == 1) {
        printf("\nPedra amassa tesoura");
        return 1;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == 3 && jogada_comp == 2) {
        printf("\nTesoura corta papel");
        return 2;
    }
    if (jog_usuario == jogada_comp) {
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int jog_usuario, jogada_comp, x;

    jog_usuario = ler_jogada();

    jogada_comp = ler_comp();

    imprime_jog(jog_usuario, jogada_comp);

    x = calc_resultado(jog_usuario, jogada_comp);


    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            printf("\n\nGanhei! Quem sabe voce ganha na proxima...!");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n\nVoce ganhou!!!Parabens!");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n\nEmpate! Vamos de novo!");
            printf("\n");
            main();
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O problema é que ele cai no `if(jog_usuario==3&&jogada_comp==1);` mesmo quando não foram essas as opções escolhidas? Não entendi muito bem qual o problema.

Comment: Para qualquer seleção vai ser informado que pedra amassa tesoura

Comment: Dica para a próxima vez que você fizer uma pergunta: é mais fácil reproduzir o erro se você mencionar claramente qual é a entrada do programa que leva ao erro. Também é útil tentar criar uma versão reduzida do programa que ainda apresente o comportamento indesejado. Quanto menor o programa, mais fácil para achar o erro!  (por exemplo, você pode fazer uma versão que não lê da entrada e já chama `calc_resultado(1,3)` direto

Answer (score 2):

Você tem vários `;` depois dos `if`s:

```
if (jog_usuario == 1 && jogada_comp == 3); {  // remova o ; depois do )
    printf("\nPedra amassa tesoura!");
    return 2;
}
// há também outras instâncias desse erro no código
```

O que está acontecendo é que o if está sendo executado, mas há um *empty statement* após ele (o `;`). Depois disso, o `{` abre um bloco que é sempre executado (já que não está em nenhum `if`). Por isso que essa função sempre retorna `2`.

Answer (score 0):

A primeira obs é que vc dá um return na função ler_jogada() antes de entrar no while(). Ou seja, essa sua validação nunca acontece.

Segunda coisa é esse trecho `jogada_comp = 1 + rand() % 4;` define valores de 1 a 4 (deveria ser 1 a 3) e isso invalida algumas situações.

E obviamente o problema com os ";" já citados.